# How to localize Android DatePicker?

Tags: android, android-widget

I put the `DatePicker` on my `Activity`. Everytime I launch my app I see english version of date in the `DatePicker widget: Oct 15 2012`. But I want to have a local version of date (russian) when I start my Activity. I've tried to define the locale before `UI` initialization. But it doesn't help. Is there any possibility to make it without extending `DatePicker` class?

Comment: How is it seem russian local version? please give an example. Like Окт 15 2012,

Comment: It should be like "15 Окт 2012".

Answer (score 2):

In fact there is no need to override this class. But when I started to do it, I found info about special method "reorderpickers" which is specially designed to localize datepicker (automatically). My mistake was in setting Locale to English in the previous activity (to define English locale for password). That's why the standard method didn't work. So anybody who has the same problem check your code whether you have changed Locale.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom datepickerdialog. For make this, that link help you;

http://coffeebreak.hiq.se/2011/09/09/fixing-androids-datepickerdialog/

Answer (score 0):

Additional information for DataPicker and application locale you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257014/set-language-to-french-in-android-datepickerdialog)